# How does validation_curve calculate test_scores

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I was going through the sci-kit learn documentation for `validation_curve` and saw that it returned two different sets of data:

Returns

> train_scores: array of shape (n_ticks, n_cv_folds) Scores on training sets.
>
> test_scores: array of shape (n_ticks, n_cv_folds) Scores on test set.

In the given function, we pass only one X and y array, how does it calculate the test_scores from the passed training data, does it perform an inherent `train_test_split`  ?

```
sklearn.model_selection.validation_curve(estimator, X, y, *, 
param_name, param_range, groups=None, cv=None, scoring=None,
n_jobs=None, pre_dispatch='all', verbose=0, error_score=nan)
```

Example of such a scenario

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import validation_curve
>>> from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
>>> from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge

>>> np.random.seed(0)
>>> X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
>>> indices = np.arange(y.shape[0])
>>> np.random.shuffle(indices)
>>> X, y = X[indices], y[indices]

>>> train_scores, valid_scores = validation_curve(Ridge(), X, y, "alpha",np.logspace(-7, 3, 3), cv=5)
>>> train_scores
array([[0.93..., 0.94..., 0.92..., 0.91..., 0.92...],
       [0.93..., 0.94..., 0.92..., 0.91..., 0.92...],
       [0.51..., 0.52..., 0.49..., 0.47..., 0.49...]])
>>> valid_scores
array([[0.90..., 0.84..., 0.94..., 0.96..., 0.93...],
       [0.90..., 0.84..., 0.94..., 0.96..., 0.93...],
       [0.46..., 0.25..., 0.50..., 0.49..., 0.52...]])
```

As we are using 3 different parameter values and 5 fold cross validation, the dimensions and values make sense for train_scores, but how are the valid_scores calculated?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does
In functions like `validation_curve()` or `GridsearchCV()` , we are supposed to produce all our data and their labels and the functions itself splits them, and at times there is a parameter as to how much split you want, like in `GridsearchCV()` , (I guess)

In the function you're using : `sklearn.model_selection.validation_curve()`
there is an argument `cv` , regarding which the documentation says

> Determines the cross-validation splitting strategy. Possible inputs
> for cv are:
>
> None, to use the default 5-fold cross validation,
>
> int, to specify the number of folds in a (Stratified)KFold,
>
> CV splitter,
>
> An iterable yielding (train, test) splits as arrays of indices

Note:

> An iterable yielding (train, test) splits as arrays of indices

[Documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.validation_curve.html)

In order to understand how validation scores are calculated we need to understand what a validation set it.
When we train our model in the above function, our dataset is divided into training set, test set and validation set.

**Validation set**:
A validation dataset is a dataset of examples used to tune the hyperparameters (i.e. the architecture) of a classifier. It is sometimes also called the development set or the "dev set". An example of a hyperparameter for artificial neural networks includes the number of hidden units in each layer. It, as well as the testing set (as mentioned above), should follow the same probability distribution as the training dataset.

and Validation score is probably calculated using the same equations as that of the test scores, its all about changing the test and train sets every time, so that the model dosen't become biased for the data could be skewed

Comment: I've updated the question with an example that may help to explain my question further. I'm interested in knowing why there are two different sets produced.

Comment: and see if this helps
  [1]: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19048/what-is-the-difference-between-test-set-and-validation-set

Answer (score 0):

Technically it is computing scores on validation rather than test set. This is done via k-fold cross-validation split.

You can specify `cv` parameter of the function which tells the function how many folds you want to create. If you don't specify `cv` (keep it `None`) then the default value 5 is used.

> cv int, cross-validation generator or an iterable, default=None
> Determines the cross-validation splitting strategy. Possible inputs
> for cv are:
>
> - None, to use the default 5-fold cross validation,
> - int, to specify the number of folds in a (Stratified)KFold,
> - CV splitter,
> - An iterable yielding (train, test) splits as arrays of indices.

taken from [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.validation_curve.html)

Comment: I've updated the question with some further explanation and examples of my query, I was interested in how two different sets are generated

Comment: Those two different sets are build via k-fold splitting (in your case you are using the default 5 folds).

Comment: Yes, that will result in 5 different splits and 5 different train scores for the dataset (which is in the `train_scores` array), how is the `valid_scores` array calculated?

Comment: That is not how it works. It will result in 5 folds, training is performed on 4 folds, validation on 1 fold, repeated 5 times so that each fold is picked once for validation and the results are averaged.

Comment: There should be only 1 array with the validation scores value, why are there two separate train and validation scores. How are the training scores calculated then ? Are the training scores calculated by checking the 4-fold trained model with the training data and is the validation data checked with predicting the final fold with the trained model ?

Comment: You have 2 sets (training and validation). Training consists of 4 folds, validation consists of 1 fold. You train your model and evaluate on both the training set and validation set. You repeat this procedure 5 times (for each fold). You end up with 5 scores for training set and 5 scores for validation set. You average these and end up with scores for training set and validation set.

Comment: `Are the training scores calculated by checking the 4-fold trained model with the training data and is the validation data checked with predicting the final fold with the trained model ?` That is exactly correct, it is just repeated few times (#number of folds you have) and the results averaged.

Comment: Thank you, I understood this, in normal cases of doing cross validation, we only get the 1-fold prediction results right ? in functions like cross_val_score and stuff

Comment: No, each time you do CV, you get as many predictions (averaged) as is the number of folds - that is the whole idea behind k-fold cross-validation, to get more precise scores via averaging across multiple trials.